# How to control reps with normal mode in caliper

Tags: caliper

I am able to control reps when i run benchmark in debug mode. 
sh ~/projects/poc/caliper/scripts/caliper --debug-reps 1  com.parquet.benchmark.BenchmarkParquetDirectWrites

However when i run in regular mode sh ~/projects/poc/caliper/scripts/caliper com.parquet.benchmark.BenchmarkParquetDirectWrites   it runs the benchmark 1000 times. I want to control the value that is set to reps.  I have two benchmarks one write and other read and i want each to be run X times and not 1000 times.

Comment: What version of Caliper are you using?  IIRC, the only thing you should be able to control is how long it runs, not how many reps it runs.